# How Do You Tell The Difference Between List and List Of Lists

Tags: python

how do you differentiate list and list of lists in python3?
i would like to return True if its list of lists and False otherwise.

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = [[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9],[10, 11, 12]]
print(type(list_1))
print(len(list_1))
print(type(list_2)) 
print(len(list_2))
```

out is :

```
<class 'list'>
3
<class 'list'>
3
```

Comment: why not type(list_1[0]) ?

Comment: test `list_1[0]` instead of `list_1`

Comment: What is `[1, [2, 3]]` by that binary logic?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I'd never mix types like this inside a list. There are dictionaries and tuples for that.

Comment: @Sunreef One is not exclusively dealing with objects of one's own creation ;)

Comment: @Sunreef Why are tuples/dicts more suitable for storing heterogeneous collections of objects than lists? dicts require that the keys are hashable so are arguably less suitable

Comment: @schwobaseggl see my answer...

Comment: @Chris_Rands Maybe it's because of my C++ background but when I iterate over a list I expect every element of the list to behave the same way. With tuples, while it is still possible to iterate over them, I like the immutability that guarantees that, after you create it, a certain index will always contain the same type. Dictionaries provide keys that also give a clue for the type of the object you're dealing with.

Comment: @Sunreef If you have that expectation (or at least if you want to enforce it) you should use `array.array` or similar rather than `list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the type of the first element:

```
isinstance(the_list[0], list)
```

i.e:

```
>>> isinstance(list_1[0], list)
False
>>> isinstance(list_2[0], list)
True
```

---

However, what do you mean by a list of lists? Is the following a list of lists?

```
[1, [1, 2, 3], 1, 1]
```

If so, then you can check if *any* of the elements are lists:

```
any(isinstance(l) for l in the_list)
```

What about the case when they are all list? Is the following the only true "list of lists"?

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

If so, then you can check if *all* the elements are lists:

```
all(isinstance(l) for l in the_list)
```

However, although these questions are important, for your example, the first snippet will suffice.

Comment: Note that this is only safe if you know `list_x` is a `list` (or sequence) at all.

Comment: @schwobaseggl That information is implicit in the question -**between a _list_ and a _list of lists_**. Of course, if there is a possibility of the list being empty (length `0`), then yes, you could change to something like: `len(the_list) and isinstance(the_list[0],  list)` which would work due to the short-circuiting of `and`. Or, you could use a `try...except...`

Comment: My remark was not meant as a criticism of your answer, just a general note that the code you posted makes presuppositions (x is a list, x is non-emtpy) that may hold in the OP's particular case but may not in similar cases.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Didn't take it as one!

Answer (score 0):

Check if every item in your list is an instance of `list`

```
is_list_of_list = all(isinstance(item, list) for item in your_list)
```

Comment: I think he wants to verify if it's list of lists?